# Google App Engine to MongoLab security

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, httprequest, mlab

I am sending HTTP requests from GAE to MongoLab in the form of:

```
https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/rival_testdb/collections/testCollection?apiKey=someKey
```

If this request was coming directly from client side, I would be very concerned.  But since this request is coming from inside a servlet in GAE, is this a security concern?  How could I make this more secure if possible?

I would like to use MongoLab if possible, but their API only allows for putting the API key directly in the requesting URL.  So I am stuck using a URL like the one above for all API requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you can secure the API key on the server you should be good. You do not have to worry about it being sniffed on the network as all the communications are over HTTPS thus encrypting the request string and the apiKey along with it.

-will

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid concern for most public services.

Specifically for MongoLab, this discussion is present over here: https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20269612-REST-api-permissions-and-security-best-practice and it does not look like the security additions that they are talking about has been released in public.

Do check out to the link.

Having said, I am assuming that the only way that you are accessing the Mongolab API is from within your GAE Application? That at least makes it more difficult for anyone to sniff out the url from your application.

A good solution would be for MongoLab to allow a HTTP Header to be inserted before your make the REST call. Here you would some ID that identifies that it is your GAE App. And then MongoLab should be doing a check for that before permitting the call to do its work.

Comment: yes, I am accessing MongaLab's API from within GAE, and GAE is secured with user authentication.  Just seems that someone could "sniff" out the URL somehow....

Comment: I agree with Will's comment above.